# How to turn this SELECT into DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-delete

I have a set of data which I basically need to "clean"

A user inputs their favorite Fragrance into a form, and on the form I have autocomplete to aid in choice and hopefully cut down on spelling mistakes which is vitally important to the task in hand.

For example, the following is the data I have for Paco Rabanne 1 Million products - however, I want them to choose Paco Rabanne 1 Million but I don't want them to have a choice of various lotions, soaps, Deodorant etc etc it's the brand and choice of fragrance that i'm interested in.

An example of the data I have is shown below.

```
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Gift Set
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Deodorant Stick 75ml
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Deodorant
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Eau de Toilette
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Gift Set 50ml
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Shower Gel 150ml
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Eau De Toilette Spray 100ml
Paco Rabanne 1 Million After Shave Lotion 100ml
```

I have a query which takes out certain words within the item title and shows what's left

The query:

```
select DISTINCT( TRIM( LEFT(title, 
        IF( LOCATE('Deodorant', title), LOCATE('Deodorant', title) - 1, 
            IF( LOCATE('Shower', title), LOCATE('Shower', title) - 1, 
                IF( LOCATE('Refillable', title), LOCATE('Refillable', title) - 1,
                    IF( LOCATE('Spray', title), LOCATE('Spray', title) - 1,
                        IF( LOCATE('ml', title), LOCATE('ml', title) - 1,
            999
        )
    )
  )
))))) FROM `PRprod_FRAGRANCES`
```

This basically selects from the table whilst omitting any duplicate line with Deodorant in the title, or Shower etc etc but I want to permenantly delete the records instead of running this query every time which is expensive as the table has over 200,000 rows

Essentially, I want to turn the query around so it doesn't not show the lines I don't want, but, actually deletes them instead.

Unless there is another way to attack this issue?

This is the table definition:

```
field, type, NULL, Key, Default, Extra

autoc_id, int(11), NO, PRI, , auto_increment
title, varchar(128), YES, , , 
genre, varchar(128), YES, , , 
author, varchar(128), YES, , , 
actors, varchar(256), YES, , , 
artist, varchar(128), YES, , , 
main_category, varchar(128), NO, , , 
dateadded, timestamp, NO, , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Comment: Simplest solution is to use a `WITH`. e.g. `WITH results ( <select> ) DELETE FROM results`

Comment: @BradChristie - Not in MySQL it's not.  It doesn't support WITH/CTEs

Comment: D'oh. Mis-read and didn't recognize MySQL. My apologies, I'm thinking about SQL-Server

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - Give us more info on the table and the logic you need...  Do the records have primary keys?  Say we identify a dozen records that return the same result to the function you gave, how do we identify which record to delete?  etc, etc

Comment: @Dems I have rewritten the question as it was a little confusing, hopefully clearer now.

Comment: You should be storing the Brand/Fragrance Line in their own tables.  You _are_ doing that, correct?  Please include your table structures - I'm assuming you don't actually want to delete all _product data_ from your database...

Comment: @X-Zero Hi, no, this is from an XML feed so don't have separate data otherwise this question wouldn't exist. I have split the data such as product title etc into a separate table just to feed the autocomplete so yes, i can and want to delete from this data

Comment: Your table definition does not match your apparent use.  There are also a number of conceptual issues with that table structure (256 varchar named `actors`?  You're not storing multiple values in there, are you?)  In any case, If this is initially being created from an XML stream, what does the XML stream contain - you may be able to extract the relevant information from there.  I would recommend creating a brand/product line table to put the results of the `SELECT` statement in.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still a bit vague.

In your example you have the data...

```
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Gift Set
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Deodorant Stick 75ml
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Deodorant
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Eau de Toilette
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Gift Set 50ml
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Shower Gel 150ml
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Eau De Toilette Spray 100ml
Paco Rabanne 1 Million After Shave Lotion 100ml
```

Are there any other fields in your table though?  Such as an id, etc?  Or is it just one field?

And do the examples above only ever appear once, or do they appear multiple times each?

Breaking your data down into groups based on your code gives the following groups...

```
Original                                           | After Processing

Paco Rabanne 1 Million Deodorant                   | Paco Rabanne 1 Million
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Deodorant Stick 75ml        | Paco Rabanne 1 Million
Paco Rabanne 1 Million Shower Gel 150ml            | Paco Rabanne 1 Million

Paco Rabanne 1 Million Eau De Toilette Spray 100ml | Paco Rabanne 1 Million Eau De Toilette Spray 10

Paco Rabanne 1 Million Gift Set 50ml               | Paco Rabanne 1 Million Gift Set 5

Paco Rabanne 1 Million After Shave Lotion 100ml    | Paco Rabanne 1 Million After Shave Lotion 10

Paco Rabanne 1 Million Gift Set                    | Paco Rabanne 1 Million Gift Set

Paco Rabanne 1 Million Eau de Toilette             | Paco Rabanne 1 Million Eau de Toilette
```

Note:  I think you don't want a `- 1` in the `ml` filter.  It turns `100ml` into `10`.

In the case of the first group, do you want all records deleted and replaced with a single record saying just `Paco Rabanne 1 Million Deodorant`?  Or do you want 2 of them deleted, and keep 1 of them?  And if so, how should we determine which to keep?

In the case of the next three groups, each group only has 1 record in it, but you've chopped the `0ml` off the end.  Do you want to replace those records with the shortened version?  Or do nothing with them?

The final two groups also only have 1 record each, and the filter did nothing to them.  Do they get left alone?

Then, once you've processed this, will new data get added again and again?  Do you need code that you can run repeatedly, or do you need to do this just as a single run?

Unfortunately, without a lot more information I don't think we're going to be able to help much.

Comment: I know its messy but there's not much i can do about the data set I'm afraid - ideally I want to return Paco Rabanne 1 Million for the whole set, just that one line, but not sure that's going to be able to be done.

Comment: Its a single run initially but I can cron it as yes, new data will turn up periodically so I know it's always going to be a work in progress

Comment: The initial question still stands though, is it possible to reverse the SELECT into a DELETE statement?

Comment: My questions still stand though.  "Reversing a SELECT into a DELETE" isn't a valid question.  We need to know more about the table...  I asked if the table has an id field.  Do you have the whole table definition?

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like an inadequate data model to me :

If you have control over how many tables the data is stored in, and can add tables at will, the cleanest solution would be to have two tables : one for the fragrances, one for the packaging.

Comment: Agreed, but how do you split the data which is the original question really..and yes, inadequate i agree but have to work with what i'm given